# How to add an if statement to a struct initialization

Tags: if-statement, go, struct, preprocessor

I'm trying to add an if statement in a nested struct, and whenever I try to build I get: `syntax error: unexpected if, expecting expression`.

I've found a simple code that shows what i'm trying to do:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Salary struct {
    Basic, HRA, TA float64
}

type Employee struct {
    FirstName, LastName, Email string
    Age                        int
    MonthlySalary              []Salary
}

func main() {
    e := Employee{
        FirstName: "Mark",
        LastName:  "Jones",
        Email:     "mark@gmail.com",
        Age:       25,
        MonthlySalary: []Salary{
            Salary{
                Basic: 15000.00,
                HRA:   5000.00,
                TA:    2000.00,
            },
            Salary{          //i want to add a condition "if true" then add this salary struct
                Basic: 16000.00,
                HRA:   5000.00,
                TA:    2100.00,
            },                // till here
            Salary{
                Basic: 17000.00,
                HRA:   5000.00,
                TA:    2200.00,
            },
        },
    }
```

And I found that this might be done through preprocessor, which I'm totally clueless about.

Please note that the struct is imported from another package on my original code and I can't change the way it's declared and used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put logic inline in a struct. You must do it outside of the variable declaration. But this is easy. For example:

```golang
func main() {
    // Initialize a slice of `salaries` with the first
    // value you know you need.
    salaries := []Salary{
        {
            Basic: 15000.00,
            HRA:   5000.00,
            TA:    2000.00,
        },
    }
    if /* your condition */ {
        // conditionally add the second one
        salaries = append(salaries, Salary{
            Basic: 16000.00,
            HRA:   5000.00,
            TA:    2100.00,
        })
    }
    // And finally add the last one
    salaries = append(salaries, Salary{
        Basic: 17000.00,
        HRA:   5000.00,
        TA:    2200.00,
    })
    e := Employee{
        FirstName: "Mark",
        LastName:  "Jones",
        Email:     "mark@gmail.com",
        Age:       25,
        // And here include them in the variable declaration
        MonthlySalary: salaries,
    }
```